# What is the difference between version and data_version in magento resources?

Tags: php, magento

```
mysql> select * from core_resource;
+-------------------------+------------+--------------+
| code                    | version    | data_version |
+-------------------------+------------+--------------+
| adminnotification_setup | 1.0.0      | 1.0.0        |
```

I never see a difference in the value between these two columns and I'm not sure exactly what the data_version is for.

Is this something that is useful?  is it anything I can benefit from using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data_version` and the corresponding so-called "data upgrade scripts" came about in CE1.4.

Data install/upgrade scripts are identical in form and function to "regular" install and upgrade scripts. They simply are executed later during initialization with the main environmental difference being that there is a store object and an initialized request object, though I can't imagine an appropriate use of the latter in the upgrade workflow.

From `Mage_Core_Model_App`:

```
public function run($params)
{
    //snip...
    if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) { //cache hook
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    } else {
        $this->_initModules(); //triggers "normal" install & upgrade workflow
        //snip...
        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
            //snip...
            $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
            $this->_initRequest();
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates(); //data upgrade scripts
        }

        $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
    }
    return $this;
}
```